# Install one way valve on basement drain?

Tags: plumbing, basement, drain, flooding

We have a "secondary" drain line in our basement, connected to the kitchen sink, dishwasher, and laundry waste. Cast iron waste line runs to the basement floor, where the pipe then runs out of the back of the house and to a drainage ditch/creek, with one drain...box? along the way (PVC node w/ drain lid).

The house was built in 1934, I'm not sure when this went in, but it definitely doesn't seem correct. During longer periods of rain and/or snow melt, this creek runs fairly high, higher than the basement floor in fact, and water comes in the basement easily. The sump pump runs but isn't enough to stop water flowing into the basement.

Would it make sense/be possible to add a backwater valve or some kind of one way valve to prevent the water coming straight up the drain?

Thanks!

Comment: What you are referring to is a check valve. It sounds like you have a pseudo dry well for gray water. But, are you sure it's coming in through the waste pipe? If it's a high water table (temporary or otherwise), it's probably seeping in around the pipe, where the wall meets the floor etc... Basements aren't typically water tight and most times other methods are needed to mitigate water intrusion.

Comment: You have a drain for these 3 fixtures and _another_ drain for the rest of the fixtures? This drain runs directly into a local creek? Definitely built in the 30s and not to _any_ version of modern code. It'll cost you, but I'd suggest that you look into getting these 3 lines plumbed into the rest of your DWV piping to go to a proper septic tank system or city sewer (presumably where the rest of the drain water goes). You probably won't be able to sell the house without doing this.